# Is there a way to put a self destroy password on Ubuntu disk encryption?

Tags: disk-encryption

Is there a way to put a self destroy password on ubuntu disk ecncryption ? Or self destroy after n bad password attempt ?

When someone ask you to entre the password, you can enter the "self destruct" password who blank the disk... not a bad idea ;-)

Best regards.

Comment: Formatting the drive can take a while and it can take even longer to securely destroy it (in a way that it can't be recovered). Instead of formatting it, maybe assign a new random encrpytion to it so that nobody knows it and nobody can unlock it.

Comment: Really a good question.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of an implementation for Ubuntu which uses LUKS. But there is a patched version of Truecrypt available which implements exactly this. It was presented at Brucon under the name ["Moar Anti-Forensics for the Louise"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHvvhukyO-c). You can find the [source on Github](https://github.com/int0x80/anti-forensics).

There currently is no patch (I'm aware of) which supports this for the `dm-crypt` module within Ubuntu.